# Curl Response is Empty after posting data via post php

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

I have a form where user puts his apiKey then that after checking for errors if everything is good the processing script post the key via curl to my server for verification. then my server should return success true | false and error code if false. but when I send the file the curl response is empty.

```
$post['apiKey'] = $apiKey;    
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://www.pawnhost.com/phevapi/verify_api.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);

$res = curl_exec($ch);
if ($res === FALSE) {
    echo "Curl Error:" . curl_error($ch);
}

curl_close($ch);

print_r($res);
```

Script we are submitting to:

```
<?php 

define("ERROR_HEADER_URL", "Location: " . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] . "?error=");

require("includes/initialize.php");

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST') header(ERROR_HEADER_URL . "invalidRequest");

if (!isset($_POST['apiKey'])) header(ERROR_HEADER_URL . "verficationFailed");

$apiKey = escape($_POST['apiKey']);

if (isInputEmpty($apiKey)) {
    header(ERROR_HEADER_URL . "emptyFields");

} elseif (!$apiKey == 25) {
    header(ERROR_HEADER_URL . urlencode("invalidKey"));

} else {

    $response = [];

    if (getApiKeyUserDetails($apiKey, $connection)) {

        if (getApiKeyUserDetails($apiKey, $connection)['apiKeyUsed'] > 0) {
            $response['success'] = false;
            $response['error'] = 'apiKeyUsed';
        } else {
            makeApiKeyUsed($apiKey, $connection);
            $response['success'] = true;
        }

    } else {
        $response['success'] = false;
        $response['error'] = 'invalidApiKey';
    }

    return json_encode($response);

}
```

Comment: Do you get an error message? is $json empty, too? You can try:if(curl_errno($ch))
{
    echo 'cURL-error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}

Comment: @Marco I did, no error

Comment: What does `$post` in `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);` look like ? Going to [the api url](https://www.pawnhost.com/phevapi/verify_api.php) is looking for specific data and is flaky at best.

Comment: Could you check the detail of request by using `curl_getinfo()` before `curl_close()`?

Like this:
```$res = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch));```

and see what happens with it.

Comment: @Jamie_D The data looks like this: IH1XJ4bRw2pMTI9QZIYxuIFKH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to send as output the `$response` not `return` it:

instead of

```
return json_encode($response);
```

use

```
echo json_encode($response);
```

---

Also note that if eihter `isInputEmpty($apiKey)` or `!$apiKey == 25` evaluate **true** then execution does not enther the last conditional block and you won't have any output in the body of the response.

The script logic is that for some kind of errors a specific header is set to notify the error.

The curl script that send the request should inspect headers too.

To do so you may use the following code to be placed before `curl_exec`

```
$response_headers = [];

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION,
    function( $curl, $header ) use ( &$response_headers )
    {
        $len = strlen( $header );
        $header = explode(':', $header, 2);
        if( count( $header ) < 2 ) { return $len; } // ignore invalid headers
        $response_headers[ strtolower( trim( $header[0] ) ) ] = trim( $header[1] );
        return $len;
    }
);
```